# How do I stop a page being published as soon as it is approved?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have to submit pages to be approved but I don't want the page to be published as soon as it is approved. Once the page has been approved I would the like to schedule the page being published, does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a default process that cannot be modified.

According to this [Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/approval-flow-for-modern-pages-a8b2e689-d4a1-4639-8028-333c0ece30d9),

> Once the page approval is configured, authors will be able to submit
> page for approval. The page will be published once the page is
> approved. Rejecting a page will put that page back to draft status.